# Генерация ключей Putty из консоли

Tags: windows, администрирование

Можно ли как-то сгенерировать ключи для ssh туннеля используя консольные команды putty?

Comment: https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_generate_an_ssh_key_on_windows_using_putty/

Comment: Меня интересует генерация именно из консоли, а не вождение мышкой по экрану

Comment: puttygen с параметрами нужно запустить

Comment: Ну это и так понятно, не понятно с какими именно

Comment: @НиколаКривошея `Ну это и так понятно, не понятно с какими именно` Ну если это вам и так понятно -- попробуйте продемонстрировать. У меня на моей машине не работает ни `--help`, ни `-h`, ни `/?`.

Comment: @ilyaplot `puttygen с параметрами нужно запустить` [Да ладно](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704089/putty-key-generator-command-line-interface)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Никак](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704089/putty-key-generator-command-line-interface). [Такой же ответ даётся на странице программы](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/puttygen-batch.html).

Утилита puttygen -- это GUI утилита для генерации ключей.

Если вам нужны ключи SSH - то генерируйте их в unix-системах, правда и формат их будет unix.

При генерации из unix у вас будет пара файлов id_rsa и id_rsa.pub, а у putty свой собственный формат ключей - будет два файла, .pub и .ppk

При помощи программы puttygen можно сгенерированные ключи конвертировать в unix-форматы (в меню Conversions -> Export...), а вот как в windows или unix конвертировать ключи в формат putty из командной строки -- я не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Однако есть возможность сделать это с помощью другой утилиты.
генерацию *nix rsa ключей можно организовать через ssh-keygen (UNIX):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "my@email.ru" -f ./my_rsa
```

соответственно в текущей папке создастся my_rsa и my_rsa.pub
далее с помощью winscp.com (в Windows):

```
winscp.com /keygen my_rsa -o my_rsa.ppk
```

и получится ppk файл из командной строки.